# What does the statement ImageView obj = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.demo); mean?

Tags: java, android

If I have an `ImageView` with `id "demo"`. And I write its `onClick` as fade.
In `Main_Activity.java`, if I create a method as:

```
void public fade(View view)
```

and inside it I write :

```
ImageView obj = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.demo);
```

So, what does this mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means you are inflating the ImageView with Id `demo` from XML layout file and assigning it to imageView object.

Answer (score 1):

That means the view in your xml file with id R.id.demo is being converted as a java object

Answer (score 0):

It means converting the xml view into java object.

so that it can be used as an View Object, and you can perform operations on that object.

Answer (score 0):

Below method perform the action for the onClick method that you define in the xml.

```
 android:onclick="fade" 


void public fade(View view){
 // Code for button onClick action . 
}
```

Whenever a user click on the button this method will trigger and the code inside the method will run .

```
ImageView obj = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.demo);
```

This code means that you have a ImageView in the XML file as example :

```
               <ImageView
                  android:id = "@+id/demo" 
                   android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

You are referencing or finding the imageView with using the id which is demo in your case by method `findViewById();` . 
If you don't have any ImageView in your activity xml , than you gonna get a null pointer exception. Check your activity xml for the appropiate name.